# How do I add an event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, vimeo, addeventlistener

Im using swfobject to embed the vimeo video, it's pretty simple,

```
var vimPlayer;
function vimeo_player_loaded(id){        
    vimPlayer = document.getElementById(id);           
    vimPlayer.addEventListener('play', function(){
        alert('Playing');
    });
    vimPlayer.api_play();  
}
```

`vimPlayer.api_play();` Does play the video just fine! However, How can I bind a listener to that function so that I can perform other tasks? The listener I have added does not fire at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('video').bind('play', function (e) {
    // do something
});

try using this...
```

http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: I really would rather do this with their api, I didn't state this in the post, but it's for a plugin I'm writing, I also don't want to depend on html5 only

Comment: You hav to pass 1 more parameter for eventlistner see i have shared an simple example...

Answer (score 0):

Adding event listener takes three params, here's an example:

```
function doSomething() {
   alert('Image clicked');
}

var myButton = document.getElementById('my_button_id');

myButton.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Flash Embeds, where `play()` is prefixed to `api_play()`, the need to prefix also includes `addEventListener()`:

```
vimPlayer.api_addEventListener('play', function () {
    alert('Playing');
});
```

This is demonstrated under [Flash Embed Code](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#flash):

> To add a listener for the `finish` event:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('vimeo_player').api_addEventListener('finish', function(event) {
>     // do stuff here
> });
> ```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately, `document.getElementById(id).api_addEventListener('play', play);` did nothing...

Answer (score 0):

I was stacking at exactly the same problem.
As long as I tried countless times,

```
function vimeo_player_loaded(id){        
    vimPlayer = document.getElementById(id);           
    vimPlayer.api_addEventListener('play', 'vimeo_play');
    vimPlayer.api_play();  
}
function vimeo_play(){
    console.log("play");
}
```

This should work fine if the player_id and id in HTML are same. 
English is not my first language. Sorry if it's difficult to understand.

Comment: Remember, all methods should be prefixed with api_ when using the Flash Embed Code. http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api