# How can I add a function to api_addEventListener to a Vimeo player with arguments

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, vimeo, swfobject

I'm creating a script which creates and plays multiple videos of YouTube and Vimeo on same page by using swfobject. This script creates a controller on a page which allows users to play, pause, stop and so on. I already succeeded to create YouTube players and Vimeo Players on same page and control the player by buttons on the controller.

What I am stacking at is adding api_addEventListener to the players. I succeeded to add api_addEventListener to events fired from Vimeo player and execute its callback function as I answered in following question.  ([How do I add an event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841618/how-do-i-add-an-event-listener/18841801#18841801))

However, I cannot figure out the way to add arguments to a function in api_addEventListener. According this page (http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api), all events of Vimeo return player_id and event if I don't get it wrong, but never returns. 
This is necessary for playing a next player when a current player finished playing, stopping the other players when a player is playing a video and so on.

```
function vimeo_player_loaded(id){
    var vimeo_player = document.getElementById(id);
    vimeo_player.api_addEventListener('play', vimeo_play(id, eventName));
    vimeo_player.api_addEventListener('pause', vimeo_pause(id, eventName));
    vimeo_player.api_addEventListener('finish', vimeo_finish(id, eventName));
}
function vimeo_play(id, eventName){
    console.log("Video is playing. id : " + id + " event: " + eventName);
}
function vimeo_pause(id, eventName){
    console.log('Video is paused. id :'  + id + " event: " + eventName);
}
function vimeo_finish(id, eventName){
    console.log('Video finished. id :'  + id + " event: " + eventName);
}
```

English is not my first language. Sorry if it's difficult to understand.

PS; I'm trying not to use any libraries for this script unless it's necessary.

Comment: Note that the listener expects a function, not whatever the function returns, `undefined` in this case

Answer (score 0):

The listener expects a function, but you're not passing a function, you're executing it. You have a few options, one is to make your functions return another function that expects the event argument:

```
function vimeo_play(id) {
  return function(eventName) {
    console.log("Video is playing. id : " + id + " event: " + eventName);
  }
}
```

And you'd call the function with the `id` which will return the function that the listener expects:

```
vimeo_player.api_addEventListener('play', vimeo_play(id));
// same with the others
```

Another option is to leave your functions as-is, and use `bind` to partially apply the `id` argument, so you'll get a function awaiting for the event:

```
vimeo_player.api_addEventListener('play', vimeo_play.bind(null, id));
// same with the others
```

Remember, functions are objects, when you use `()` you're actually calling the function, not passing it around.

Comment: I got what you pointed out regarding addEventListener. However, the code didn't work as I aimed. The first one was executed its callback function when vimeo_player_loaded(id) even Vimeo player didn't "play". The second one simply didn't work. I think the problem　lurks around Vimeo's api.